# Allowing drag and drop in a usercontrol on a web page

Tags: c#, browser

I'm building an application in C# to run in a browser window.  I want to drag and drop files from the windows explorer into a listbox.  However, when I try to pop up a dialog that contains the drop target, I get an error.

> Application attempted to perform an
>   operation not allowed by the security
>   policy.  Etc.

There are additional instructions to use the .NET Framework Configuration tool.

1. I want this to run on an end-user's machine.  If I download the .NET SDK and mess with the configuration, will this affect my application or the use of .NET on my own machine (useless).
2. Is this simply an inadvisable thing to do?  Should I either nix the drag and drop or build this as an application instead of a browser-based app?

Comment: Are you talking ASP.net (what sort of droptarget object are you speaking of)?

Comment: No.  This is all in a basic C# dll.  I have a usercontrol that's living on a webpage.  The usercontrol is popping up a dialog.  The dialog contains a listbox that's a drop target.  When the dialog is about to pop up, the error message comes.

Comment: I have since converted this to a ClickOnce application, which doesn't have these problems.  My guess is that signing the application and/or having users modify their .Net settings might resolve this, but I have not examined this avenue.  I'll leave this question unanswered for posterity unless someone objects.